# Echo not printed on page using php

Tags: php, html, server-error

I am trying to create a web page using php. The problem is that sometimes I get server errors and sometime I get nothing in return at all. At one point the server changed the file type itself. I have NO idea what the problem can be.

And since I have actually no idea what the problem is I paste the entire file here, even though I expect that it's the first few rows that is the problem (I put it here: http://www.iandapp.com/smic/subscription.php) :

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');

echo("<div id='subscribe'>");

$mail = $_POST['email1'];

//Set the locale format, etc. of date and time
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Stockholm');
setlocale(LC_TIME, "sv_SV");

//Create the db-connection
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("mydb", "myuser", "mupsw", "myschema", "3306");

//If verifying the subscription, makse sure the db is updated accordingly
if($_GET['newid'] != ""){
    //Make the subscriber a verified subscriber
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE users SET subscriber = 1 WHERE id = " . $_GET['newid']);
    if($result){
        echo("<p>Welcome to our newsletter! We will send you information about any new application or update. This will not happen too often, but once it does we hope you will have the opportunity to look into our site again.<p/>");
        echo("<p><br/>If you wish to unsubscribe from this mail-list, please visit out subscription page: <a href="http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/subscription.php"> http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/subscription.php </a> <p/>");
    }else{
        echo("<p>Somthing went wrong, please click the link again!<p/>");
    }

}elseif($_POST['email1'] != ""){ //Only do things if there is an e-mail posted

    //Make sure the ID is unique
    do{
        $rand_int = rand(100000000, 999999999);
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = " . $rand_int);

        $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        }while($no_of_rows != 0);
    echo("RAND :".$rand_int);

    //Create query for saving the new user e-mail
    $query = "INSERT INTO users(id, email, first_name, surname) VALUES ('" . $rand_int . "', '".$_POST['email1']."', '". $_POST['first_name']."','".$_POST['surname']."')";
    $re = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
    echo("Result: ".$re);

    //Check if mail already exist (Error code 1062 = dublicate entries for unique fields)
    $existing = 0;
    if(mysqli_errno($mysqli)==1062){
        echo("It seems like your e-mail already is registered. Perhaps you have been a subscriber earlier? By clicking the link that you will receive in your mail box you subscribe to the newsletter again. ");
        $existing = 1;
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '" . $_POST['email1'] . "'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $rand_int = $row['id'];
        mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE users SET waiting_for_unsubscribe = 0 WHERE email = '" . $_POST['email1'] . "'");
        if(mysqli_errno($mysqli)){
        echo("Error code " . mysqli_errno($mysqli) . "<br/>");
        echo("Error text " . mysqli_errno($mysqli) . "<br/>");
    }
        //echo("ID------ " . $row['id'] . " ri---- " . $rand_int);
    }



    //Create the link for the user to verify the subscription
    $url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/smic/subscription.php?newid=" . $rand_int;     


    $mymail = $_POST['email1'];
    $esubject = "Please verify your subscription to iAndApp's newsletter ";
    $body = "Click the link in order to verify your subscription (If you cannot click the link, just copy it and paste it into the adress field of your browser): " . $url;
    $eemail = "NoReply@iandapp.com";
    $sent = mail($mymail,$esubject,$body,"From: $eemailn");
    if($sent){
        if($existing != 1){
            echo "<br/>An e-mail with a link has been sent to ". $mymail . ". Please click the link in order to verify your subscription";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Something went wrong. Please try again and make sure you enter a correct e-mail adress.";
    }
    $existing = 0;

mysqli_free_result($result);

//If unsubscribing
}elseif($_POST['unsubscribedmail'] != ""){
    //echo("Unsubscribe........");
    //echo($_POST['unsubscribedmail']);
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE users SET waiting_for_unsubscribe = 1 WHERE email = '" . $_POST['unsubscribedmail'] . "'");

    //echo("Err code " . mysqli_errno($mysqli));
    //echo("Err text " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
    if(mysqli_errno($mysqli)){
        echo("Error code " . mysqli_errno($mysqli) . "<br/>");
        echo("Error text " . mysqli_errno($mysqli) . "<br/>");
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '" . $_POST['unsubscribedmail'] . "'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    //echo("ID------ " . $row['id']);
    //Create the link for the user to verify that he/she  unsubscribes
    $url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/smic/subscription.php?unsubscribeid=" . $row['id'];

    $mymail = $_POST['unsubscribedmail'];
    $esubject = "Please verify that you want to unsubscribe from iAndApp's newsletter ";
    $body = "Click the link in order to verify that you want to unsubscribe from iAndApp's newsletter (If you cannot click the link, just copy it and paste it into the adress field of your browser): " . $url;
    $eemail = "NoReply@iandapp.com";
    $sent = mail($mymail,$esubject,$body,"From: $eemailn");
    if ($sent) echo "<br/>A mail with a link has been sent to ". $mymail . ". Please click the link in order to verify that you will unsubscribe from the newsletters.";
    else echo "Something went wrong. Please try again and make sure you enter a correct e-mail adress.";

mysqli_free_result($result);    
}elseif($_GET['unsubscribeid'] != ""){
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE users SET subscriber = 0, waiting_for_unsubscribe = 0 WHERE id = " . $_GET['unsubscribeid']);
    if($result){
        echo("<p>You have now unsubscribed to the newsletter. Thank you for this time and we hope to see you again in the future. /iAndApp.<p/>");
    }else{
        echo("<p>Somthing went wrong, please click the link again!<p/> ".$result);
    }

}else{

echo("<div class="subscribe">
<h4>Subscribe</h4>
<p>Subscribe to iAndApp's newsletter in order to get information about new and updated iPhone games and iPhone applications, that has been released by iAndApp. </p>
<form action="subscription.php" name="subscribe" method="post"  onsubmit="return isValidEmailAndEqual()">
<p class="formlabel">Förnamn</p> <input type="text" name="first_name"/><br/>
    <p class="formlabel">Efternamn</p> <input type="text" name="surname"/> <br/>
<p class="formlabel">E-mail</p> <input type="text" name="email1"/>
<br/>
<p class="formlabel">Repeat e-mail</p> <input type="text" name="email2"/> <br/>
<input class="inputsubmit" type="submit" value="Subscribe"/>
</form>
</div>");

echo("<div class="footer"></div>");


echo("<div class="subscribe">
<h4>Unsubscribe</h4>
<p>Fill in your e-mail address and submit in order to unsubscribe from iAndApp's newsletter. </p>
<form action="subscription.php" name="unsubscribe" method="post"  onsubmit="return isValidEmail()">
<p class="formlabel">E-mail</p> <input type="text" name="unsubscribedmail"/><br/>
<input class="inputsubmit" name="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Unsubscribe"/>
</form>
</div>");

}

mysqli_close($mysqli);

echo("</div>");

?>
```

Of course, I don't expect you to go through and debug the entire application, but perhaps for the more expreienced folks out there, you know where to look.

I'm starting to get a bit stressed out here...

Please advice what the problem is and how I can solve it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What exactly doesn't echo out?

Comment: Nothing echoes out. If you access the link, you get nothing.

Comment: [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) alert..

Comment: Could you please explain. Since I'm not accessing the database while loading the page the first time, can it really be the reason, even if it is something I need to look into as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape double quotes inside html tags or use single quotes. Right now, echo thinks it's closed after `"<div class="`. Use one of these:

```
echo "<div class=\"class\">";
```

or

```
echo '<div class="class">';
```

or

```
echo "<div class='class'>";
```

Comment: No, it won't. Once again, it'll think you are ending string after `...id="`.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem. It's easy to get crazy. I stole the code form a different site I made and it was working all the time (but of course I start to wonder now...). It has been resting for some time, I woke it up and tried it and now it didn't work. Development is not always fun... :)

Answer (score 5):

eror in code:

```
echo("<div class="subscribe">
<h4>Subscribe</h4>
<p>Subscribe to i
```

in 1-st line you just close the string by 2-nd quote
you just need to correct code

Answer (score 1):

If you dont get any reposne from server (document is clear) or you have server errors but this is not all the time and sometimes script works fine it could be memory limit problem.

```
do{
    $rand_int = rand(100000000, 999999999);
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = " . $rand_int);

    $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    }while($no_of_rows != 0);
```

This part of code dosn't look good for me, I suggest you to use auto_increment at id field in db (so id will be unique all the time)

Comment: No, guess you're rigth there. I don't think that is the reason for my problem though. I will improve it later. Thanks for the input.